# Is it possible to add space between the button and its border [Javafx]

Tags: javafx

[image]

Is it possible to add space between the button and its border? I want the black color to fill the button but not completely it should leave out a little spacing between the border.

The button layout is width:200, height:40
The CSS used:

```
.button:focused, .button:hover{
-fx-text-fill: aquamarine;
-fx-border-color: -fx-text-fill;
-fx-border-radius: 50px;
-fx-background-radius: 50px;
-fx-scale-x: 1.1;
-fx-scale-y: 1.1;
-fx-background-color: #34495E;
}

.button:hover{
-fx-cursor: hand;
-fx-background-color: black;
}


.button{
-fx-font-size: 20px;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;
-fx-text-fill: #f0f0f0;
-fx-border-color: -fx-text-fill;
-fx-border-radius: 5 5 5 5;
-fx-border-width: 2px;
-fx-background-color: #34495e;
}
```

Comment: Can you 1. post the code you are using to create this button, and 2. explain what you mean more clearly? It looks like you have a black background and a green-ish border (created either with an explicit border or a nested background). So what do you want to see in the space between the border and the background? Should that part be transparent, so you see whatever's behind it? Or it should be some other color?

Comment: @James_D transparent background is needed between the spacing. I had found the background-insets property but don't understand how I'd apply to it. I've posted the CSS

Comment: No time to test but try `-fx-background-color: transparent, black; -fx-background-insets: 0,5;`

Comment: @James_D Thanks a lot! Works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple backgrounds in JavaFX CSS, which are rendered one on top of the other in the order they are specified. Each background can have a corresponding insets, enabling you to see a portion of the backgrounds which come before it.

So, to leave a gap between the border and the background, you can specify a transparent background before the "main" background, with a positive insets for the latter:

```css
.button {
  -fx-background-color: transparent, black ;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 5 ;
}
```